# complex regex pattern with multiple OR segments using python

Tags: python, regex

The code block below shows what I'm trying to do.  I hope it's self explanatory.

```
sentence = "the heros aka justice league. \ 
            john also known as jacob when he's not being john"

identities = ['the heros', 'heros', 'justice', \
              'justice league', 'john', 'jacob']

bridges    = ['aka', 'also known as']

# desired matches:
#     the heros aka justice league
#         heros aka justice league
#     the heros aka justice
#         heros aka justice
#     john also known as jacob
```

My general strategy is to define three capture groups ..

```
ie - using ('|'.join(identities))
           ('|'.join(bridges))
           ('|'.join(identities))
```

.. to form the patterns inside the groups.  Here's the pattern without any lookarounds or other complications, just to establish a baseline:

```
( 
    (\bthe heros\b|\bheros\b|\bjustice\b|\bjustice league\b|\bjohn\b|\bjacob\b)
    ([\s\.]*) 
    (\baka\b|\balso known as\b) 
    ([\s\.]*) 
    (\bthe heros\b|\bheros\b|\bjustice\b|\bjustice league\b|\bjohn\b|\bjacob\b)
)
```

but those other complications (lookarounds, etc) are no doubt key, and where I need help.

To complicate things further, I need the character locations of each captured element.  For example, I need to know where the captured "john" is, but not the other non-captured "john" at the end of the sentence.  Thus, I'm using re.finditer to return match objects in python because those match objects include the offsets.

edit ----------------------------

For those who want to see my continuing efforts ... this pattern:

```
(?=(the heros|heros|justice|justice league|john|jacob)
\s*(aka|also known as)
\s*(?=(the heros|heros|justice|justice league|john|jacob)).)
```

produces the following matches:

[('the heros', 'aka', 'justice'), ('heros', 'aka', 'justice'), ('john', 'also known as', 'jacob')]

which is close.  But "league" is never matched.

further edit -------------------------

Ah .. but a lookahead at the end of a pattern doesn't really make sense.  You have to use a lookbehind (?<=).   However that also proves challenging in this case because of the error *[ look-behind requires fixed-width pattern ]*.  For now, then, I've resorted to looping through the elements in the last capture group and using them one by one.

```
for element in identities:
    '(?=(the heros|heros|justice|justice league|john|jacob)
     \s*(aka|also known as)
     \s*('+element+')))'
```

Comment: You can put `\b` outside the alternatives: `\b(the heros|heros|justice|...)\b`

Comment: You've described what you're trying to do, but haven't asked a question. What problem are you having? Where is the code that uses `re.finditer`?

Comment: I thought my code would only be a distraction.   In any case, I can't show every variation I've tried.  The question is how to capture all of the results listed in the question at once.  Clearly that involves overlapping matches.  I hope that helps.

Comment: The point is, I know that some people are going to sit down and try to write out some code.  Instead of making them work through whatever mess I happen to have, I wanted to try to provide the best starting point I could.

Comment: Ah.  Sorry for multiple comments.  The only reason I mentioned re.finditer is so that people don't suggest completely different methods that can't yield offsets.

Comment: That's not the way this site works. We don't write code for you, we help you fix your code. Post what you think is the closest to the solution, we'll tell you what you did wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: You should read [ask].

Comment: I'm not trying to get people to write my code for me.  Just trying to ask the question in what I think the most helpful and least confusing way.  As it says in the How to Ask section that you pointed to, "Not all questions benefit from including code."

Comment: What are you expecting other than code?

Comment: Read the paragraph before that, and the sentence after it. This is the kind of question that should have code.

Comment: Regardless of that, you still haven't explained what problem you're having. There's no question anywhere, so what are we supposed to answer?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve using a  look around?

Comment: My understanding was that a lookaround would allow the regex to go back into a section of text it just matched and rematch a different section of it (a subset) because the match is discarded and only the fact that it matched is remembered.  Thus (?=(every good|good boy|boy|does|fine) can match both "every good", "good boy" .... in the sentence "every good boy does fine".   .. whereas without the lookaround, "good boy" is never matched.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the final edit at the bottom of the question.  A (not perfect but workable) solution is posted there.